# Pass data between siblings - flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, data-management, state-management

I have three widgets, a crud widget, a crud form widget, and a crud list widget. For simplicity, let's call them widget A, B and C, respectively.

Widget A is just a wrapper for B and C.

So the hierarchy is like this

```
A
-B
-C
```

*Note that B and C are siblings, and A is the parent

Widget C has just a list of users, and when tapping a user in that list, I'd like widget B to get that user data, and populate the TextFormFields with that users data.

**What's the best practice for passing the data in widget C, to widget B?**

Widget A has a *user property* in it's state, and has a function it can pass down, that *takes a user as an argument*, and updates it's own state when called. Widget C calls this function when one of the users in the list are tapped.

I've confirmed that the state in widget A is being updated when that tap occurs.

My problem that I'm facing is that, though I have a user property on widget b, that widget does not get the updated values, nor does it redraw.

I have the initial value for my form fields in widget B like so... `initialValue: widget.user.firstName.isEmpty ? user.firstName : widget.user.firstName;`

So the logic is simply, if the data passed down has a value, use that value, otherwise, use the model value in state, **not** the value of the user being passed.